# Not Able to Install Angular CLI using npm

Tags: angular, npm, proxy, angular-cli

I'm trying to install Angular CLI using the command`npm install @angualr/cli@1.7.5` but I'm facing the below error (screenshot). I tried investigating about the error. It seems like there is some proxy issue and could not able to resolve it. Any suggestion ??[image]

Comment: can you ping the repository? 

`ping registry.npmjs.org`

If that works, try to fetch a simple file from the repo: 

`npm view npm version`

Comment: @vhbazan, I did that. Not got any reply from the registry.nmpjs.org.

Comment: which version of npm are you using?

It seems to be a connection issue, something is not allowing you to connect to that repository/server. Try to check if you have a firewall or a anti-virus that might be blocking you. Also, try to restart your PC.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem with your node/npm and not with Angular.
Have look [fixing npm permission page](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) or [commons error npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/common-errors)

Comment: I don't think the version 1.7.5 is available. Try with a different version 1.7.4 for example.

Comment: @vhbazan , even I tried with 1.7.4 as well. But the error is same

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a company network try to get off that and connect to a public wifi like your home internet and try running this npm command